# Cucumber + Junit + Extend Test Steps (use IDs in next step)

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, cucumber, junit, mock

Details:

We currently use Mockito/ Wiremock (in different teams), Junit and Cucumber in our test procedure.

And test cases are functional, but we want to extend them with regard to post procedures.

Currently we have a test case that asks for the customer ID (used here is Mockito + Wiremock + Junit 4 different Teams) this test should now in a further step use the customer ID (that he has determined) to create another test case based on the determined customer ID.

Source:

Feature File Information: (Working Scenario), in the Give part we only start Mockito or Wiremock

**Feature File Example:**

```
When <headerName_PropFile> and <headerValue_PropFile> is added to request
When POST request for <JsonRequest> is sent
Then response code is the <StatusCode>
Then Validate Responses <expectedValue1>
Then Validate Response <expectedValue2>
Then Validate against Swagger
```

In the further course we have of course adapted the API according to Cucumber, there given,when, then formulated, but we are missing a possibility how we could use the step definition results like a determined customer ID in further steps.

**Example for API + Cucumber**

```
      @When("^PATCH request for (.+) is sent")
      public void sendPatchRequestF3(String requestBodyFile) throws Throwable {​​​​
      //GenerateReport.stepName = "When PATCH request is sent with request body";
      Object requestBody = setDataInJSON(getValue(requestBodyFile));
      request.body(requestBody.toString());
      FilterableRequestSpecification httpRequest = (FilterableRequestSpecification) request;

      Reporter.addStepLog("Request URL : " + httpRequest.getURI());
      sendRequest("PATCH");
      Reporter.addStepLog("Response Body: " + response.prettyPrint());
      //GenerateReport.reportStepStatus("pass", "Response body: " + response.prettyPrint());
      }​​​​
```

Questions:

- How can we integrate values determined in further steps into the
  feature file in such a way that the new values are integrated
  accordingly, thus creating new test queries?

Comment: Did you do any research? Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/43067617/3001761?

Comment: yes but i use other search string ;) Thank´s for the informations, i will take a look on it. Maybe my answer is special?

Comment: FWIW I searched for https://www.google.com/search?q=cucumber+use+value+returned+from+step and got a lot of results. If your specific context *is* special, [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I think I found what I was looking for, you were right about the search. Should I remove the post again, or leave it for now? 

or do you want to write an answer that I and others can rate?

Comment: I don't think it would be appropriate to copy across someone else's post. It doesn't seem like there's a discoverability problem, I'd suggest deleting.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a global variable. Save it in a base class that you inherit or you can import a helper class/file in your test.

```
// DataFile.java
class DataFile {
    string myVar;
}
```

```
// Test1.java
import DataFile;
...
@Then("I get and save my response") {
    DataFile.myVar = thing1.value;
}
```

```
// Test2.java
import DataFile;
...
@When("I submit my new code") {
     string thing1 = DataFile.myVar;
}
```